# Can't exclude file contents from text search

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

I'd like to exclude the contents of a file log/output.log from the global text search (cmd + shift + f). I tried adding glob patterns to the "Search: Exclude setting" but I still see search results from it.

[image]

I also tried `**/output.log` and `output.log`. And restarted VSCode.

Any ideas?

Btw, the setting says "Configure glob patterns for excluding files and folders in fulltext searches and quick open". Ideally I'd not exclude the file from quick open (I want to be able to open the log quickly), only exclude the contents from the search. But if it's not possible I'm fine with excluding it from both.